# Can you recommend a Shockwave Flash (SWF) to "movie" conversion library for OS X?

Tags: flash, macos, video, format-conversion

I've Googled this in various ways, and there's no shortage of software to do it. Since this is something I'm unlikely ever to do again, I'd prefer a free solution, but I'm also willing to pay if the best solution requires it.

I'm a fairly skilled software developer in multiple languages, so if anyone knows of a library that will do it (and is available for OS X), I have no problem "rolling my own".

I have a large number of SWF files for a training course I'm taking, and I want to convert them to H.264 for use on my Apple TV so I can watch them on my television more easily. This must be **Mac OS X** software, compatible with an Intel Leopard machine.

I don't mind having to convert to an intermediate format, but it sure would be nice to go directly to H.264.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: this is a typical question for superuser.com

Comment: Agreed, but notice that it was asked before superuser.com existed.

Comment: Also, if you read the body of the question carefully, you'll note that I was looking for a *library* to do this programmatically.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yeah, I'm well aware. Again, *this question was asked before superuser.com existed.* Also, I dispute this policy. This is clearly a programming question. I needed to take SWF files and convert them programmatically to another format. Asking how to do that is (or should be, IMHO) far from off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) takes FLV files as source and can convert to h264. It is free, relies on VLC (which is again available in 64 bit on Mac so you can use Handbrake 64) and can manage a processing queue.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [ffmpegx](http://www.ffmpegx.com/) which I am use fairly often and which works perfect for my needs.

But it looks like it cant convert .swf - but to be sure you should try it. It's free software.

greets

Answer (score 0):

As Flash is an interactive, code driven format (i.e. not linear like a video) you cannot normally just convert to a video format. Even if your swf is a linear animation, there may still be ActionScript code controlling the animation.

What this means for you is that you just need to make a good video/audio capture of the swf, for which you can use a whichever free screen capture software you choose (you'll probably need a fast computer).